# HTTP request and View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, http, nsarray

I have this code

```
func presentationlum() { 
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://raspberrypi.local/etatlum.php")!)

    let Session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    var JsonDict : NSArray = []
    let dem = Session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        do {
            if let _JsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions() )as? NSArray
            {
                JsonDict = _JsonDict
                if JsonDict[0] as! String == "0"{
                    Dark1.hidden=true
                } else {
                    Dark1.hidden=false
                }
            } else {
                print("Cannot parse JSON answer")
            }
        } catch {
            print("An Error as occurred : \(error)")
        }
        print(JsonDict)
    })
    dem.resume()
}
```

I want to get the response of my server and use it to hide the UIButton Dark1.

But it doesn't work how can I fix it ?

Comment: What doesn't work? In which case (do/if/else/catch) do your app goes? Avoid naming var starting with an uppercase.

Comment: Why do you declare an empty NSArray as `JsonDict` and then you make a new one with `if let` and then again you copy this one to the first one?! Also, as Larme told you, variables and properties should be lowerCamelCase. And don't force unwrap your optionals. You should also use `self.Dark1` instead of `Dark1` in the closure.

Comment: I have try to use self.Dark1 but then I have a fatal error

Comment: It probably means that Dark1 is not properly hooked to the button in Interface Builder. See explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Comment: i will give u a big advice. use afnetworkingit is much more easier with u

Comment: @BashirSidani Nonsense. Using AFNetworking (or its Swift equivalent, Alamofire) has nothing to do with the issues at hand, and wouldn't help OP a bit.

Comment: Where is this method being called? Is it in a `viewWillAppear`? It could be you need to move it to `viewDidLoad`.